# $.ajax parsererror when handling JSON containing a new Date() element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, mongodb

I am serializing JSON grabbed from a MongoDB and returning it to the javascript client that requested it via a $.ajax call.

The $.ajax call looks like this:

```
function server_request(URL, httpMethod, dataObject) {

    var output = "";
    var typeofData = "json";
    var dataToSend;

    console.log('server_request ajax [' + httpMethod + '] request to ' + URL + ' with ' + JSON.stringify(dataObject));

    if (dataObject !== null) {
        dataToSend = JSON.stringify(dataObject);

        $.ajax({
            type: httpMethod,
            async: false,
            dataType: typeofData,
            data: { jsonPost: dataToSend },
            timeout: 2000, // Timeout in milliseconds
            url: URL,
            success: function (data) {
                output = data;
            }
            , error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('Ajax post error jqXHR: ' + JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                console.log('Ajax post error: ' + textStatus);

                output = new Object();
                output.textStatus = textStatus;
                output.errorThrown = errorThrown;
                output.nutshell = 'n/a - exception thrown';

                console.log('Ajax post error: ' + JSON.stringify(output));
            }

        });
    }
```

On the server I am returning JSON from an MVC controller as follows:

```
return new ContentResult { Content = responseDoc.ToJson(), ContentType = "application/json" };
```

where responseDoc is a MongoDB BsonDocument.

It all works fine as long as I don't have a date element within the JSON.  As soon as an element is added which looks like this: `\"usersynctimestamp\" : new Date(1378905216401)` then the $.ajax call fails with a parsererror.

When it fails, I can still see the problematic JSON via the error XHR data, as follows:

```
Ajax post error jqXHR: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{ \"nutshell\" : \"yes\", \"mongoDocument\" : { \"_id\" : { \"$binary\" : \"TJop8k0+KUKfrEVzI/vV+A==\", \"$type\" : \"03\" }, \"companyname\" : \"Apple\", \"databasename\" : \"Apple\", \"users\" : [{ \"_id\" : { \"$binary\" : \"y2dgrURxUEq/iCdI/eIoPw==\", \"$type\" : \"03\" }, \"email\" : \"marketpoint@evoite.com\", \"firstname\" : \"Ian\", \"password\" : \"aa\", \"surname\" : \"Smith\" }], \"usersynctimestamp\" : new Date(1378905216401) }, \"mongoDocumentCollectionName\" : \"clients\" }","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}
```

So, it seems that $.ajax does not like the new Date() syntax created by the serializer in the MongoDB C# driver.  Can anyone advise me how to get around this problem?

Many thanks

Comment: JSON has no notion of date serialization/deserialization. You have to use a tool like moment.js that takes care of that for you or implement the logic youtself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to force the MongoDB driver to output strict json as follows:

```
string jsonStrictString = responseDoc.ToJson(new MongoDB.Bson.IO.JsonWriterSettings() 
                {
                    GuidRepresentation = GuidRepresentation.CSharpLegacy, 
                    Indent = false, 
                    OutputMode = MongoDB.Bson.IO.JsonOutputMode.Strict
                });
```

This will allow $.ajax to correctly parse the response.